# How to calculate homography matrix of plane using the homography of its orthogonal plane?

Tags: 3d, geometry, homography

I have an image in of 2 orthogonal planes.
I have a homography matrix of one of this planes.
I want the homography for the other plane.

my question explicitly is:

1- can I compute the homography directly from the other homography?

2- if not, what other data do I need to add the current homography to compute the other one? and what is the algorithm for that?

thank you guys

Comment: This question was [also posted on the Math SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1436466/35416). Please don't do that. Pick one community and wait for an answer there. This question looks mathematical in nature, so it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: hi @MvG. Thank you for your response.As this topic is specially used by programmers I though I might find my audience here.

Comment: @MvG I also clarified my question in [link] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1436466/how-to-calculate-homography-matrix-of-plane-using-the-homography-of-its-orthogon)